# Remove grouping gridlines from RadGridView WPF c#

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-grid

[image]

This is a sample gridview from the Telerik Demos, but I was wondering how you can removed these gridlines that appear after you group items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get rid the the vertical lines with :

```
<Style TargetType="grid:GridViewIndentCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BasicBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="grid:GridViewIndentCell">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Width="25" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Gridviewgroupstyle code im working through

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewGroupRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewGroupRow}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewGroupRow}">
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_GroupExpanderGrid">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="PART_HeaderRow" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="ContentRow" Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandStateGroup">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="BottomBorder">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" Storyboard.TargetName="IconOuterBorder">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <Thickness>0</Thickness>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" Storyboard.TargetName="IconInnerBorder">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <Thickness>1,1,0,0</Thickness>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="180"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Border x:Name="ToggleButtonBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" telerik:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingClip="True">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Border Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" telerik:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingClip="True" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                            <Border.Visibility>
                                                <Binding Path="ShowHeaderAggregates" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                                    <Binding.Converter>
                                                        <telerik:BooleanToVisibilityConverter/>
                                                    </Binding.Converter>
                                                </Binding>
                                            </Border.Visibility>
                                            <telerik:AggregateResultsList HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="False" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                                <telerik:AggregateResultsList.ItemsPanel>
                                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                </telerik:AggregateResultsList.ItemsPanel>
                                                <telerik:AggregateResultsList.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <telerik:GridViewAggregateResultCell AggregateResult="{Binding}" IsTabStop="False">
                                                            <telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                                                <telerik:Office_BlackTheme/>
                                                            </telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                                        </telerik:GridViewAggregateResultCell>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </telerik:AggregateResultsList.ItemTemplate>
                                            </telerik:AggregateResultsList>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border x:Name="IconOuterBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" telerik:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical">
                                            <Border x:Name="IconInnerBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1">
                                                <Path x:Name="ExpanderButton" Grid.Column="0" Data="M0,0L1,0 2,0 2,0.99999991 3,0.99999991 3,2 4,2 4,0.99999991 5,0.99999991 5,0 5.9999999,0 7,0 7,0.99999991 5.9999999,0.99999991 5.9999999,2 5,2 5,3 4,3 4,4 3,4 3,3 2,3 2,2 1,2 1,0.99999991 0,0.99999991z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="5" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Width="7">
                                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                </Path>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderButton" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Opacity="0" telerik:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"/>
                                        <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Padding="0,0,10,0" telerik:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical">
                                            <ToggleButton.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                                <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"/>
                                                                </Border>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="9,0,0,0"/>
                                                </Style>
                                            </ToggleButton.Style>
                                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding GroupHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding GroupViewModel}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </ToggleButton>
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" telerik:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingClip="True">
                                            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <Border x:Name="PART_IndicatorPresenter" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Grid.Column="0" telerik:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding RowIndicatorVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="25">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFE4E4E4"/>
                                </Border>
                                <telerik:IndentPresenter Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" IsTabStop="False" IndentLevel="{TemplateBinding Level}" telerik:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical">
                                    <telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                        <telerik:Office_BlackTheme/>
                                    </telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                </telerik:IndentPresenter>
                                <Border x:Name="Content" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <telerik:GridViewVirtualizingPanel x:Name="PART_GridViewVirtualizingPanel" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False"/>
                                        <telerik:GridViewGroupFooterRow x:Name="Footer" IsTabStop="False">
                                            <telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                                <telerik:Office_BlackTheme/>
                                            </telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                        </telerik:GridViewGroupFooterRow>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                                <Border x:Name="BottomBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" telerik:SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingClip="True" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="GroupHeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE4E4E4"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25"/>
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
```